# Hidden Markov Model initial probability reestimate: Why $\pi^*_i = \gamma_i(1)$ instead of $\pi^*_i = \frac{\gamma_i(1)}{\sum_{j = 1}^N \gamma_j(1)}$

Tags: machine-learning, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms, hidden-markov-models

In the sources I consulted it states that in the Baum Welch algorithm the reestimate of the initial probability of state $i$ of the HMM is $\pi^*_i = \gamma_i(1)$. But $\gamma_i(t)$ is the probability of being in state ${\displaystyle i}$ at time ${\displaystyle t}$ given the observed sequence ${\displaystyle Y}$ and the parameters ${\displaystyle \theta }$ ([quote wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm))

So, then why does this probability not need to be normalised like so? :

$$\pi^*_i = \frac{\gamma_i(1)}{\sum_{j = 1}^N \gamma_j(1)}$$

After all normalizing is what is done for the reestimate of the transition probabilities and the emission probabilities too.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2215962/14578, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72428/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is defined to be a probability.  A probability is by definition already normalized.  In particular, we are guaranteed that

$$\sum_{j=1}^N \gamma_j(1) = 1,$$

as there are only $N$ possibilities for the state that you're in at time $1$, and these $N$ cases have no overlap.